# How do I upload mailing content in 4.6?

Tags: civimail

I love the new Civi mail enhancements in 4.6 but just wondering what happened to the "upload content" button. Is it still possible to upload mailing content from a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the HTML rich text editor, there is a button called "Source". You can use this to send custom HTML:

1. In a text editor (e.g. Notepad), open the desired file. Copy all the markup.
2. In the CiviMail UI, click "Source". Paste the markup.

Comment: This is "The" solution, but I think the question speaks to usability - sounds like import HTML or import HTML template might make a nice feature request.

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't a real replacement for the old upload html button. While the new editor is nice, it modifies my custom html email and breaks it all together. Even if I don't click out of the 'Source' mode. It should not modify the html code at all! That was the nice thing about the upload option.

Comment: I have to agree with Sonicthoughts and Apotropiac. Many organisations let external designers take care of the newsletter design and just want to upload the finished file - not C&P any code...

Also, the editor modifying the code has been a huge pain for a long time - the upload button was a good workaround.

Comment: If ckeditor's "Source" view munges the code, then that seems like a bigger issue that would affect more apps (not just CiviMail). Anyone know if ckeditor has a solution -- such as an extra option or plugin?

Comment: In my case, I had thought ckeditor was munging the HTML but it was actually an error in my HTML. I believe that ckeditor is stripping some excluded tags and trying to correct incorrect HTML. So it can depend on how messy the source HTML is.

Answer (score 2):

You can also copy and paste content into the editor.  I see that there is even a paste from Word button so hopefully most needs can be met.

Luckily with the new, more robust, editor any necessary modifications needed after pasting should be easier to make.